# How to remove a div containing an image when click on "X" using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have made a box with an image in it, and an X at the right top corner. and when I click on it I want it to delete the image, box and the X. However nothing happens. Please don't be to harsh I'm new to Jquery and javascript.

```
<span class="removethis">    
<div class="imformationbox1" >  
<div class="col-lg-12">
<button type="button" class="deletebutton" id="" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;<  /span></button>    
<a href="#" id="" title="Image 2"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250 class="thumbnail img-responsive"></a>    
</div>
</div> 
</span>

<script>
$( ".deletebutton" ).click(function() {
$( ".removethis" ).remove();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is okay. you just need to wrap the .deletebutton function around document.ready . http://jsfiddle.net/ghjhjz03/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its very simple .. just use [**closest()**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
<script>
$(document).on('click',".deletebutton" ,function() {
 $(this).closest(".removethis" ).remove();
});
</script>
```

or you can use [**parent()**](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click',".deletebutton" ,function() {
     $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
    });
</script>
```

if you dynamically append this data just use

```
$(document).on('click',".deletebutton" , function(){});
```

Comment: Think some thing is wrong with my set up, nothing is happening. :/

Comment: @KerrialBeckettNewham what error you got in a console? .. this code should work

Comment: @KerrialBeckettNewham http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/fbswwesk/   and   http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/fbswwesk/1/

Comment: @KerrialBeckettNewham  and you forget to close "  in image src    src=" "  at the end

Comment: It doesn't seem like there was an issue with the original code posted in the question : http://jsfiddle.net/ghjhjz03/5/

Comment: just to understand, how would you do that by id rather than class?

Comment: @KerrialBeckettNewham  1st ID must be unique for an element .. that mean you shouldn't make same id for more than one element .. 2nd  with ID  you just need to use #  instead of . for class .. if you id = "mainDiv"  so use it like $('#mainDiv') .. thats it :)

Comment: @KerrialBeckettNewham you Welcome .. Good Luck :)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef if i were to add in a bootstrap alerts to slide down, how would i do that? http://jsfiddle.net/24pwjvm1/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/24pwjvm1/2/ this works for one image, but if i close another nothing comes up.

Comment: @KerrialBeckettNewham in jsfiddle you need to include jquery from the top left hand side  http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/24pwjvm1/3/

Comment: @KerrialBeckettNewham look at this and try to play around that .. http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/24pwjvm1/5/ .. Good Luck :)

Comment: @KerrialBeckettNewham this tutorials will help you alot to learn about jquery https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNb8T5NBdQg&list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810 .. it will take a time to watch but it will be so helpful for you

Comment: So it works when i remove one image, but not if i want to remove a 2ed or 3rd, 4th.. ect.

Comment: @KerrialBeckettNewham please check the console in each step .. no function called  .alert() in jquery .. http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/24pwjvm1/8/

Comment: Nice. These have been extremely useful.